# Error while reprojecting CSV-file with pyproj

Tags: python, coordinate-system, csv, pyproj

I am trying to reproject a csv-file and here's the error i get.

> File "C:\Users\jonat\Anaconda3\lib\csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
>         self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
>
> Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the
>   file in text mode?)

```py
import csv
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from os import listdir, path

#Define some constants at the top
#Obviously this could be rewritten as a class with these as parameters

lon = 'L' #name of longitude field in original files
lat = 'B' #name of latitude field in original files
f_x = 'x' #name of new x value field in new projected files
f_y = 'y' #name of new y value field in new projected files
in_path = r'C:\H4G_Geomatique\Client\2020\Longueuil\JulienLord\\' #input directory
out_path = r'C:\H4G_Geomatique\Client\2020\Longueuil\JulienLord\\' #output directory
input_projection = 'epsg:4326' #WGS84
output_projecton = 'epsg:2950' #MTM8N

#Get CSVs to reproject from input path
files= [f for f in listdir(in_path) if f.endswith('.csv')]

#Define partial function for use later when reprojecting
project = partial(
    pyproj.transform,
    pyproj.Proj(init=input_projection),
    pyproj.Proj(init=output_projecton))

for csvfile in files:
    #open a writer, appending '_project' onto the base name
    with open(path.join(out_path, csvfile.replace('.csv','_project.csv')), 'wb') as w:
        #open the reader
        with open(path.join( in_path, csvfile), 'rb') as r:
            reader = csv.DictReader(r)
            #Create new fieldnames list from reader
            # replacing lon and lat fields with x and y fields
            fn = [x for x in reader.fieldnames]
            fn[fn.index(lon)] = f_x
            fn[fn.index(lat)] = f_y
            writer = csv.DictWriter(w, fieldnames=fn)
            #Write the output
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in reader:
                x,y = (float(row[lon]), float(row[lat]))
                try:
                    #Add x,y keys and remove lon, lat keys
                    row[f_x], row[f_y] = project(x, y)
                    row.pop(lon, None)
                    row.pop(lat, None)
                    writer.writerow(row)
                except Exception as e:
                    #If coordinates are out of bounds, skip row and print the error
                    print (e)
```

Comment: What if you change `"rb"` into `"r"`?

Comment: Thank you, but i still get the same error..

Comment: what if `"rt"`?

Comment: Thank you but no same error.